# Broadcast receiver event for application update

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that's registered for `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` event.

```
    <receiver 
      android:exported="true"
      android:name=".MyReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In the receiver's `onReceive` implementation I just log the that it has been reached.

When I tested the code on Samsung device everything worked great.
When I tested the code on Xiaomi the onReceive section was never reached.

What could be the reason for this not to work on Xiaomi, does this vendor have different events that I need to register to?